# Not open set looks like the disjoint union of countably many open intervals.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

The set is the complement of $A$, where

$A = \left\{\frac{n+1}{n} \, | \, n \in \{1,2,...\}\right\} \subset \mathbb{R}$

The complement of $A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}$ because any ball with centre $1$, contains elements of $A$.

But we proved a theorem in class showing that any open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of a countable collection of intervals.

$A$ looks like its countable distinct points, so the compliment would be the union of a countable collection of disjoint open intervals.

But then the complement of $A$ would be open, which it isn't.

I'm very confused. I would greatly appreciate any clarification you could offer me.

Comment: Compliment $\leadsto$ compl**e**ment.

Comment: The complement of $A$ is a countable union of disjoin intervals, but one of these intervals is not open! Precisely, one of the intervals composing $A^c$ is $(- \infty ; 1]$ which is not an open interval.

Comment: Have you tried drawing the complement of $A$? It's not the union of countably many disjoint open intervals. It's the union $(- \infty , 1 ]   \cup (1,2) \cup (2,3) \cup \dots $

Comment: $(\infty, 1]$ is a subset of $A^c$.  $(\infty, 1]$ is a *closed interval.  That keeps $A^c$ being a countable union of open intervals

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I was being very silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complement is not a countable union of open intervals because of the problem at $1$. You could try writing it like
$$ (-\infty,1) \cup (2,\infty) \cup \bigcup_{n =1}^\infty \left( \frac{n+2}{n+1}-\frac{n+1}{n}\right)$$
but this excludes the point $1$. And there is *no* open interval containing $1$ which we could add to this union to get $A^C$, because as you said every such interval contains a point of $A$.

Comment: Yes! Thank you!